# os.walk() does not go through sub-directories when running the code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to iterate through files using `os.walk()`, which works just fine using `Python interpreter 2.7` or when debugging in `pyCharm debug console`, but when running the code, it returns just these 3 files on my C drive and does not scan subfolders.

`['hiberfil.sys', 'pagefile.sys', 'swapfile.sys']`

I am using the same code, which is

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\"):
        print(files)
```

I have checked, `pyCharm` base interpreter is set to `Python 2.7` which is supposed to be the same

Comment: What do you get when running directly in command line?

Comment: During debug if i put a breakpoint, within python console i get all the files back. I do not understand it. Sorry, I am new to `Python`

Comment: What do you mean by "running the code"? Is there anything else running in your for loop, which could cause the loop to "get stuck" or break? Is there anything else happening in your python script besides the loop?